# How do I maintain uniform cross section of a DNA structure while bending it?

Tags: modifiers

I am making a DNA finger ring and this is the basic structure below (I just added a few balls for now but once completed they will be at each junction):

[image]

The issue I am facing is that the cross section of the bars and that of the outer-frame is getting twisted and flattened - I want them to be uniformly circular in cross section. The cross section of the outer frame should be slightly larger than that of the horizontal bars.
I used this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yDwOGJYoho , to create the main DNA structure and then used a simple deform modifier to bend it into a ring.

Highlighting the issue a bit better in the image below:
[image]

Can someone suggest how to fix the issue? Even if it means completely redoing the model, I am fine with it. Thanks in advance!